# ShowDialog from an asynchronus function called in initState Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, build

I am writing a code to check if the user have the correct version of my app installed otherwise redirect him on the Playstore to update the app.

I am using `firebase_remote_config` to store a variable to keep tract of the minimum version I want the users to use.

`Package_info` to get information about users app.

`url_launcher` to redirect to playstore from the app

My problem is that  my method to check the version is asynchronous and it needs to show the dialog to the user before entering the first screen of the app.

I execute it in `initState`.  But the build method builds the first screen before the end of my asynchronous function and  my `ShowDialog` did not render.

How can I firstly show the result of my asynchronous function before the first build?

here is my code after some updates but not showing the Dialog before Navigating to another screen

```
class Splashscreen extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  _SplashscreenState createState() => _SplashscreenState();
  }

  class _SplashscreenState extends State<Splashscreen> {

  @override
  void initState() {

  super.initState();

  SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  versionCheck(context);
  });

  }

 

 Future versionCheck(context) async {
  //Get Current installed version of app

  final PackageInfo info = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
  double currentVersion =
  double.parse(info.version.trim().replaceAll(".", ""));

  //Get Latest version info from firebase config
  final RemoteConfig remoteConfig = await RemoteConfig.instance;

  try {
  // Using default duration to force fetching from remote server.
  await remoteConfig.fetch(expiration: const Duration(seconds: 10));
  await remoteConfig.activateFetched();
  remoteConfig.getString('force_update_current_version');
  double nVersion = double.parse(remoteConfig
      .getString('force_update_current_version')
      .trim()
      .replaceAll(".", ""));

  if(nVersion > currentVersion){

  showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (_) => new AlertDialog(
  title: new Text("You are not up to date"),
  content: new Text("To use the application, you must update it"),
  actions: <Widget>[
  FlatButton(
  child: Text('Go To Store'),
  onPressed: () {
  _launchURL(PLAY_STORE_URL);
  },
  )
  ],
  )
  );

  }

  } on FetchThrottledException catch (exception) {

  print(exception);
  } catch (exception) {
  print(
  'Unable to fetch remote config. Cached or default values will be used');
  }
  }



  _launchURL(String url) async {
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
  await launch(url);
  } else {
  throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
  }


  

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ScopedModelDescendant<UserModel>(builder: (context, child, model) {
  return new SplashScreen(

  seconds: 4,
  navigateAfterSeconds:
  model.isSignedIn ? HomePage() : SuggestLoginPage(),

  image: new  Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png', fit: BoxFit.cover,),
  backgroundColor: Color(0xff131921),
  styleTextUnderTheLoader: new TextStyle( ),
  photoSize: 100.0,
  
                  loaderColor: Colors.white
              );
          });
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a splash screen when the app running first time show your logo or a loader.

```
    class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
    }
    
    cclass _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      checkVersion();
    });
  }

  Future checkVersion({String payload}) async {
    var upToDate = false;
    if (upToDate)
     print('Navigate to Home');
    else
      return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) => new AlertDialog(
          title: new Text("You are not up to date"),
          content: new Text("To use the application, you must update it"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Go To Store'),
              onPressed: () {
                //navigate to store
              },
            )
          ],
        )
      );
  }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  "Stackowerflow",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: "Josefin",
                    fontSize: 55,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
                Image.asset('assets/images/splash.gif',width: 500,
                  height: 500,),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
```

> Don't forget to run this splash screen into main.dart

Now you can add your function into checkVersion and if up to date then return home or whatever u want to redirect but if it is not then redirect to the store

Comment: thanks for the answer but not working yet... the dialog i want to show is not showing because we already navigate to another screen after the splashscreen... any suggestions?

Comment: Not working... please i added the code i dont know maybe i am doing something wrong

Comment: I answered your question please close this, mark that answer as worked and search for how to check version control or ask a question.

Comment: thanks for your answers.... helped me a lot... even if the AlertDialog is showing, it also dissapears with the navigation without tapping any button... thats my last issue now...